# Can we access custom metadata attributes from BIM 360 docs using Forge API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

Using the forge API, we would like to query models by custom fields created in bim 360 docs ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa21H.png)). Could the API somehow provide us this possibility? We have investigated the data management api but can't find any request that handle custom attributes.

[image: see screenshot]

Comment: Not doable at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Attribute API is not available for BIM 360 Docs yet, so this is not possible to obtain attribute data by API now. Apologies for any inconvenience caused. However, you can keep eyes on here for recent updates:

- https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-docs-forum/new-bim-360-release-notes-and-bim-360-roadmap/td-p/7753472
- https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-docs-forum/latest-updates-new-knowledge-network-articles-bim-360-docs/td-p/7738068